# PHP & RegEx to find multiple links in source code

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing

(Hope the title makes sense, if there is a better way to describe feel free to update)

Summary:  I have a bunch of HTML source code that I am tasked with to walk through and pick out the specific links from.

In the code.. to identify the links I need.  All of them start with:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
```

and end with:

```
</em>
```

so I want to grab ALL links in the source code that start with and with the above examples.

There cold be 1 or 70 links that I want to grab out of the source code..

all starting with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"
```

and I want to grab everything up to (and including) the next/immediate:

```
</em>
```

I have some other regex that I using to re-format things AFTER I get the link (string) out of the source code..  but I am looking (hoping) there is a more automated way for me to parse these links out of the source code.

I put PHP, because its available to use as an intermediate step.. or I can just use Notepad++ (like I normally do)

What are my options, and what regex can be used to get multiple links out of the page without the other source code?

Update:

Here is an example of the type of link I am trying to grab in the source code (can be anywhere from 1-2 to 70+)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="PDF" border="0" height="12" src="/images/template/icn_pdf.gif" width="12" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em>
```

- The `</em>` is AFTER/OUTSIDE of the `<a href` start...

tags shown in full content:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>junk</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="PDF" border="0" height="12" src="/images/template/icn_pdf.gif" width="12" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>junk</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="PDF" border="0" height="12" src="/images/template/icn_pdf.gif" width="12" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>junk</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="PDF" border="0" height="12" src="/images/template/icn_pdf.gif" width="12" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>junk</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt="PDF" border="0" height="12" src="/images/template/icn_pdf.gif" width="12" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

rinse & repeat..

obviously the links are different..etc..

Comment: You can't just do something like this? <a\s+href="javascript:void\(0\)"(.*?)<em>

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.

Comment: Could you please post a part of your code?

Comment: What exactly within the `<a...` and the `</em>` are you trying to capture? Is the `</em>` within an `<a ...>...</a>` element or after it? With that information, we can better figure out how to capture what you want.

Comment: If you can use PHP, use a DOM parser, but we cannot help you with that since we do not know what the HTML looks like. With Notepad++, you can try using `<a\s+href="javascript:void\(0\)"[\s\S]*?</em>` or `<a\s+href="javascript:void\(0\)".*?</em>` with *dot matches newline* option.

Comment: Sorry,,, you guys are right, I should have posted an example HTML sample to use in testing.  

Also, I 'can' use PHP if it helps make things easier.  I didnt even think of  PHP Dom parser as a solution..

I have updated the original post with an example of the HTML link I am trying to grab

Comment: @dustmouse - where would I use that regex sample..  (its not working in Notepad++ to find anything)

Comment: @stribizhev

The first one seems to work good..  

Heres where I'm lacking.. how can I get a recursive 'search'.. and output the 'finds' (results) to a separate file or list?  (parse/strip out the links it finds?)

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Nice to see an example string, still, the tags might have some common parent. If you could post a larger example including the `<a>` tag parent, I could provide code in PHP. In Notepad++, you can use `[\s\S]*?(<a\s+href="javascript:void\(0\)"[\s\S]*?</em>)` and replace with `$1\n` and then manually remove the trailing part from the last `</em>`.

Comment: @ stribizhev

Sorry about that.. the parent container/element is a TD 

updates in original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a non Regex solution:
Class:

```
<?php

class Parser {
    private $_position, $_html;

    function __construct($html) {
        $this->_html = $html;
    }

    private function SkipTo($text) {
        $p = strpos($this->_html, $text, $this->_position);
        if ($p !== false)
            $this->_position = $p + strlen($text);
        else
            return false;
        return true;

    }

    private function ReadTo($text) {
        $p = strpos($this->_html, $text, $this->_position);
        $result = false;

        if ($p !== false) {
            $result = substr($this->_html, $this->_position, $p - $this->_position);
            $this->_position = $p;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function Get($from, $to) {
        $result = array();
        while($this->SkipTo($from)) {
            $result[] = $this->ReadTo($to);
        }
        return $result;
    } 
}
```

Use like this:

```
require_once 'parser.class.php';

$html = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"window.open('/some/url/presentations/index.php?filename=1105 name-v2.pdf'); return false;\"><strong>Presentation Title</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img alt=\"PDF\" border=\"0\" height=\"12\" src=\"/images/template/icn_pdf.gif\" width=\"12\" /><br />
Presenter Name XYZ - <em>Institution Name XYZ</em>";

$parser = new Parser($html);
$result = $parser->Get('<a href="javascript:void(0)"', '</em>');

foreach($result as $res) {
    echo $res . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but seems there is an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\projects\misc\parser.class.php on line 7

Line #7:  $this-_html = $html;

Comment: Sorry, it -does- work.. I think I had a copy/paste error at first.

That being said it seems to cut-off the initial search params?

`<a href="javascript:void(0)    </em>`

A not in the results returned...  How can I have them included?

Safe enough to do this:

`$result[] = $from . $this->ReadTo($to) . $to;`

Comment: @whispers you can do as you said, or , in skipto `$this->_position = $p + strlen($text);` change to `$this->_position = $p` and in readto change `$result = substr($this->_html, $this->_position, $p - $this->_position);` to `$result = substr($this->_html, $this->_position, $p + strlen($text) - $this->_position);`

Comment: Accepted answer!  thanks. pretty easy to follow and use.  Got me almost everything I need, except for some that didnt follow normal formatting.

Comment: @whispers glad it helped, you can manage to change the class to your needs!

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
//define html as a string here
var Regex = new RegExp('<a +href="javascript:void\(0\)"[^]*?<\/em>', 'g');
var Matches = [];
while ((result = Regex.exec(html)) !== null) {
    Matches.push(result[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer trying it now.. seems this is javascript instead of PHP based?  (not that I have a preference)..  

I do have a problem with the html 'string' has both double and single quotes..  so if I try to define it as a variable, it just 'breaks' the string.

I escaped all single quotes and dumped my HTML into a var, but the string is breaks when goes to a new line?  How can I prep my HTML to get into a 'string'.. to even begin to run the RegEx loop?